# Flask: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I created a small `Flask` service. However each time I tried to use the `say-hi` endpoint, I get the following message:

```
{
    "message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."
}
```

My Flask service looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, abort, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class HelloResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return { 'message': 'Hello' }

class SayHiResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('name', required=True, help='Name cannot be blank')
        args = parser.parse_args()

        return { 'message': 'Hello ' + args['name'] }

api.add_resource(HelloResource, '/hello')
api.add_resource(SayHiResource, '/say-hi')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, load_dotenv=True)
```

However, there is not much information about why is failing.

The way I'm running is by using `gunicorn` and the `serviceEntrypoint.py` file,
which only has this content:

```
from src.api.service import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Here is my folder structure

```
.
├── requirements.txt
├── serviceEntrypoint.py
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    └── api
        ├── __init__.py
        └── service.py
```

Why the `/hello` ending works, but the `say-hi` doesn't when I call to `http://localhost:8000/say-hi?name=John`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run the flask debug server and issue your HTTP request `http://localhost:8000/say-hi?name=John`, you will see that the actual error is:

```
message "Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'."
```

There is documentation and examples [here](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#full-example), but it boils down to choosing if the request should be a GET or a POST. The way you structured your request - you are passing 1 field only, the username - it looks like a GET, in this case you should have:

```
api.add_resource(SayHiResource, '/say-hi/<username>')
```

and class:

```
class SayHiResource(Resource):
    def get(self, username):
        return { 'message': 'Hello ' + username }
```

if you want to implement a POST request, please trace in the documentation the example that is triggered by the call: `curl http://localhost:5000/todos -d "task=something new" -X POST -v`

Update:

for using query parameters, you can use the `request.args`:

```
api.add_resource(SayHiResource, '/say-hi')
```

class:

```
class SayHiResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        username = request.args.get("username")
        status = request.args.get("status")
        # print(query_args)
        return { 'message': 'Hello {}, your status is: {}'.format(username, status) }
```

example:

```
[http_offline@greenhat-35 /tmp/] > curl 'http://localhost:8000/say-hi?username=lala&status=enabled'
{
    "message": "Hello lala, your status is: enabled"
}
[http_offline@greenhat-35 /tmp/] >
```

Comment: I'm passing an URL parameter to do a query. I'm not trying to get the username resource.

Comment: so you still need a GET request i guess. the above code will work for you, you need to insert your code in the `get` method above.

Comment: There is a clear difference between doing `api/<some_resource>` and `api?name=some_resource`.

Comment: are you familiar with what the `'/say-hi/<username>'` means? <username> is the value of variable you are passing in your request , John in your initial question.

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with that. But as I said before, that is not they way I want to do things. The idea is that I can pass more values like `/say-hi?name=john&age=2`. That is completely different to what you are posting. I'm trying to use query parameters.

Comment: For some reason, the official documentation of flask_restful doesnt have examples with query parameters, so i provided answer using their examples. Please see updated answer for query parameters, you can use flask's feature the `request.args`.

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this is to add `location='args'`, so that reqparse uses only the query string value:

```
parser.add_argument('name', required=True, help='Name cannot be blank', location='args')
```

The reason for the issue is that [`Argument`](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/v0.3.9/flask_restful/reqparse.py#L74) has 'json' as the default location and recent versions of Werkzeug (used by flask) will raise an exception when reqparse tries to read json data from the (non-json) request. This should probably be considered a bug in reqparse, but it's [deprecated](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.8/reqparse.html), so don't count on an update.